# How can I see spanish accents when reading a CSV file using pandas read_csv and encoding latin-1?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, encoding

I don't get errors while doing read_csv:
df_Conf_Factor_de_concentracion = pd.read_csv("Conf_Factor_de_concentración.csv", encoding='latin_1')

However, when I try to display or compare values, accents are replaced with other ascii characters:
df_Conf_Factor_de_concentracion.head(3)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Xok.png)
This is a screenshot from the csv file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIkp2.png)

I was expecting that accents look just like they are stored in the csv file, for instance, in the first row, column "Clase de piso" it should say "De concreto sobre vigas metálicas", rather than "De concreto sobre vigas metlicas"

By the way, I have tried with others encoders (cp1252, iso-8859-1) having the same results.
I am using Mac and pandas v1.3.5.

Please help!

Comment: Whaat happens if you do not set `encoding`?  What happens if you use `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: It fails when trying to read_csv. UTF-8 is the default encoding.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the MacOS platform, and I'm wondering if you use a different browser with your `jupyter` notebook, will the characters appear differently?

Comment: I tried with Chrome rather than the default Safari, but it's the same problem: accents are not showing correctly. Can you please try in Windows?

Comment: I have no Windows platform to try it on, sorry.  Your spreadsheet app seems to display the characters properly - Can that app display which character encoding it is using for that file?  Does the output from `head Conf_Factor_de_concentración.csv` look correct?

Comment: Maybe it's not clear in the image I attached, but .head or print function show accents á, é, í, ó, ú like a square [].

Comment: I am using Latin1 encoding

Comment: I'm wondering if your `jupyter` notebook output can _display_ any accents, etc.  What's the output for `print('concentración')`?

Comment: It does display accents fine

Comment: You just gave me an idea and it finally worked. I opened the excel file, then I saved it as a CSV utf-8 file, the I could successfully open it with pd.read_csv using the default utf-8 encoding.